# Opinions on RESTful route for DELETEing of nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Given a typical nested resource of a photo with comments, the route to create a comment would look something like:

```
POST /photos/{photo_id}/comments
```

Now, for deleting the comment, would you still use a "nested" route?  ex:

```
DELETE /photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}
```

or

```
DELETE /comments/{comment_id}
```

The pro of the nested route is that it mirrors the creation URL and doesn't require any additional entries in routes.rb.  The pro of using a top-level URL is that you technically don't need the photo_id to get the comment to delete.

Thoughts?

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 3):

How you model the `comments` resource depends heavily how you see the resource `comments`.

In case a comment could exist without a photo and could be associated with 0 to N resources like `photo` then you should model your comments like this

```
GET    /comments/{comment_id}
DELETE /comments/{comment_id}

PUT    /comments/

POST   /comments/{comment_id}/associations/photo/{photo_id}
```

In case a comment is always associated with a resource and cannot exist without being associated with a resource then you should stick with

```
POST   /photos/{photo_id}/comments

DELETE /photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}
```

I guess the confusion how to model the comment is driven by the database model where every comment gets a unique id that is unique among all comments and not just unique in a `photo_id` and `comment_id` combined key. I suggest not to let the database model leak to the resource model and go for a model that fits your conceptional understanding of the resource.

Comment: +1 for 'not to let the database model leak to the resource model'

Answer (score 2):

Can you `GET` this?

```
GET /comments/{comment_id}
```

I guess not. But if you can't `GET` a resource, you can't `DELETE` it, too.

So only your second option is RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm just using nested route for delete, means i used:

```
DELETE /photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}
```

to delete comments of a photo. If i use:

```
DELETE /comments/{comment_id}
```

so i have to create one more route for this? I don't find any reasons to create a separate route for delete, I think it's not necessary. The nested resources have create url and path for us, and they are follow convention, why don't we use them?  I just want to keep it simple and  will not do extra work for things already have.